# perl regex error: Modification of a read-only value attempted

Tags: regex, perl

I have this perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $line (" ^?[?12;12A", " ^?[A") {
    print "$line\n";
    $line =~ s/\s?[[:cntrl:]]\[(\?)?([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[a-zA-Z]//g;
    print "$line\n";

}
```

Those are two strings that start with a space, then a control character, then some regular ascii characters. It results with this error:

```
$ perl foo.pl
 [?12;12A
Modification of a read-only value attempted at foo.pl line 6.
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case $line is a read-only value.

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Work with an actual array like `my @testarray = (" ^?[?12;12A", " ^?[A");`
2. Assign the value of $line to another variable and modify that:

   ```
   my $tmp = $line; 
   $tmp =~ s/\s?[[:cntrl:]]\[(\?)?([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[a-zA-Z]//g;
   ```

Comment: `print $line =~ s/.../.../r;` would also do

Answer (score 3):

In a [foreach](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops) loop the loop variable ("topicalizer") is but an alias for the currently processed list element; by changing it we really change the element.

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop. Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that element will fail. In other words, the `foreach` loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

The loop in the question iterates over a list of *string literals*, and those are read-only. Attempting to change that is a [fatal error (perldiag)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#Modification-of-a-read-only-value-attempted) (this  case, of `foreach`, is given as one example.

Some ways around this are shown in [Hameed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73492820/4653379), to store them in an array, or to assign the string literal to a variable first.

Or, use the ["non-destructive" modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) on the substitution operator, `s///r`, which doesn't change the original but returns the changed value (or the original if it didn't change)

```
my $new_line = $line =~ s/.../.../r;
```